# Is there a way to Combine the below two UNIX Commands in efficient manner in single piped chain of commands?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, rpm

**Problem Statement**

1. I would like to identify a package and its description using `rpm -qi ${pkgName}`.
2. `cat -n` on the output of (1) will yield me which line on wards 
   description section starts.

   Ex:- 15th Line in case atom IDE editor in rpm.
3. I know I can solve the output and formatting part again using this line number as 
   `rpm -qi atom | awk -v n=${lineNum} 'NR>=n'`. Here `lineNum` would be 15.

This is inefficient and I would like to use the `rpm -qi` command only once and then achieve this extracting out the description section on wards. Does anybody have a way to do this ?

**Additional requested input**

```
[anand@ldnpsr2937 ~]$rpm -qi atom
Name.       : atom
Version     : 1.42.0
Release     : 0.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sun 12 Jan 2020 10:23:12 AM
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 590646918
License     : MIT
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : atom-1.42.0-0.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Sat 14 Dec 2019 03:38:56 AM
Build Host  : 2580f855e2eb
Relocations : /usr
URL         : https://atom.io/
Summary     : A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.
Description : 
A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.
[anand@ldnpsr2937 ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a detailed problem statement here. Only thing if you could add samples of `rpm` with your current complete command's output it will be much easier for us to understand problem more, kindly do edit your post and let us know please.

Comment: Also if you  have bigger script since I am able to see variables named `lineNum` and `pkgName` in your post, better do let us know more details on it.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I have added the info. but jxh has given solution already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of combining something, just use `rpm` command to query a specific tag. No `sed` and fancy stuff needed at all.

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{description}' atom
```

Comment: That has to be the best answer.  Never cared to explore the man page of rpm , I should read more on query language now!! , Thx Danika!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted something like:

```
rpm -qi atom | sed -ne '/^Description/,$ p'
```

Where we use `sed` to print everything after the matched line. But, as demonstrated in a different answer, `rpm` has a native method to achieve this.